# Pega texto especifico em uma string

Tags: python-3.x, string

Eu estou tentando pegar um texto especifico dentro de uma string.

```
import unicodedata
address = "Rua Fiandeiras, 429, São Paulo, SP, 04545-000"
string "".join(x for x in unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", address) 
                if not unicodedata.combining(x) if not ch.isdigit()).replace(",", "").replace("-", "").lower()
```

Saída

```
rua fiandeiras sao paulo sp
```

Meu objetivo é chegar nessa formatação de string `sao-paulo-sp` serviria para qualquer estado que eu indicar na variável

Comment: O formato do endereço será sempre "Rua, Número, Cidade, Estado, CEP"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso o endereço seja sempre formatado como "Rua, Número, Cidade, Estado, CEP". Uma solução que encontrei foi utilizar o modulo `unidecode`:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
address = "Rua Fiandeiras, 429, São Paulo, SP, 04545-000"
string = unidecode(''.join(address.split(',')[-3:-1]).strip().replace(' ', '-').lower())
print(string)
```

Saída:

```
sao-paulo-sp
```